# Alexa skill having trouble avoiding the FallbackIntent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm having trouble avoiding the FallbackIntent.  I'm writing a skill that labels different days Red Days or Blue Days.  Using the dev console Utterance Profile I keep getting the fallback intent when I ask "is today a red day".  I have a specific sample of that question in my interaction model so I don't understand why my intent is not getting identified.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

[image]

specyfying the skill name does not help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving is not enough, you missed the "build model" button so the utterance profiler will be able to evaluate your utterances.

[image]

After building, you can see it work properly.
[image]

Also, I recommend you to keep `AMAZON.FallbackIntent` in case your user is saying something not defined in your Interaction model. You might want to catch that.